# SPF record for a domain/site

Tags: dns, spf

I have been asked by a client to provide the SPF record for one of my sites but have no idea what or where I can find this??

I presume these can be found within my WHM or CPanel installation for the site - any advice on how to locate this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a SPF record in your DNS server.

To understand what is SPF record, you can follow this link http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33786